# WebService receive decimal value with either "," or "."

Tags: c#, web-services, c#-4.0, soap, globalization

I have a .Net webservice with a webmethod which receives a Decimal type parameter. It only works if the webservice caller uses '.' as separator.

I want to be able to receive this value either with comma or point separator, due to the "multi-culture" nature of my company's system.

I've tried to create a custom SoapExtension to read the raw XML that was sent, and replace "," with ".". Unfortunately I could read the raw XML but coudn't change it.

Is there a easier way?

Comment: I would just define a "." as *the* valid decimal separator. This is no different than defining ISO8601 (or a subset thereof) as a valid date. The pretty culture-specific formatting should occur outside the data-model, such as a client that provides the user with correctly formatted inputs boxes.

Comment: If a "dual separator" solution is impossible, it would be fine to change the decimal separator to ",", since this is the pattern in my country (Brazil). Is there a way to change it? I've already used globalization (pt-BR) on web.config with no success.

Answer (score 1):

If you have several cultures that you work with, either **add that culture to a request header or as a property**, then in C# you can easily treat the Dates and Numeric values the correct way by letting the action that treat those values that they are in a different culture as the running server.

or, **simple request them to send you in your unique format**, append that format to the header section of your method so it can be appended to the WSDL when consumed

```
/// <summary>
/// Updates client birthdate
/// </summary>
/// <param name="clientId">Client identification number</param>
/// <param name="birthdate">Birth date to update (dd-mm-yyyy)</param>
/// <returns>nothing</returns>
public void UpdateBirthdate(Decimal clientId, String birthdate)
{
     // if you want to parse the date prior to use it
     DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
     if (DateTime.TryParseExact(birthdate, "dd-MM-yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
     {
        // continue your method
     }
}
```